# Create an incoming data Magento 2 Webhook

Tags: magento2, module

I am looking into creating a module which would listen to incoming data from another custom service.

For example, the said external service would send data to domain.com/webhook (which would be magento 2 installation) and module would pick up the data and process it how it sees fit

What would be an ideal way to create /webhook URI in Magento 2 installation so upon the call would read incoming POST data and process it based on certain logic

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should implement Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface. You can check the following class as an example: vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Ipn/Index.php

You can send the key in the header and match it with Magento saved key for security. E.x:

```
$requestedHeaderKeyValue = $this->request->getHeader('header-sec-key-custom', '');
$headerKeyValue = 'THISISTESTKEY';
if ($requestedHeaderKeyValue != $headerKeyValue) {
    $this->response->setStatusHeader(503, '1.1', 'Not Found!');
    $this->response->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```